# How to avoid text and textbox overlapping

Tags: jquery, html, css, styles

[image]

```
<div class="items" style="height: 100%">
<div id="search" style="position: absolute">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off"/>
    <span class="search-icon"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="Description"">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container" style="width: 100%">
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0gL5017j/

I need text left side and textbox in right side without overlapping.

How can I avoid text box and text(description) from overlapping ?

Comment: Please post a minimal working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a Snippet.

Comment: create jsfiddle please

Comment: Remove 
`style="position: absolute"`

Comment: use need to add class for the div before the description, then only you can handle the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```css
#search {
  width:15%;
  float:right;
}
#Description{
  width:85%;
  float:left;
  word-wrap:break-word;  
}
```

```html
<div class="items" style="height:100%">       
    <div id="search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off"/>
        <span class="search-icon"></span>
    </div>
     <div id="Description">            TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
     </div>
    <div id="container" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `absolute`

```css
#search {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items" style="height: 100%">
<div id="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off"/>
    <span class="search-icon"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="Description">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container" style="width: 100%">
</div>
```

"

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code

1. You did not closed first div
2. Extra `"` added for `id="Description"`

I have removed `position:absolute` property

Try this

```
<div class="items" style="height: 100%">
    <div id="search" >
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off"/>
        <span class="search-icon"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="Description">
        TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container"  style="width: 100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
#search {
  text-align: right;
}
#Description{
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

And **[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Ramkee/0gL5017j/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

just use position absolute for Description element and move to left side , other wise remove position absolute for the text box and make the

```
#search
{     text-align: right;
  display:inline-block;
  width:300px;

}

#description
{
  width:400px;
  display:inline-block;
}


<div class="items" style="height: 100%">
    <div id="search" >
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off"/>
        <span class="search-icon"></span>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div id="Description"">
        TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
</div>
```